# What is the length of an array after both pushing to it, and assigning key-value pairs like an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is an example :

```
var myArray = []
myArray.push('A String')
console.log(myArray.length) // got: 1
myArray['aRandomKey']='An Other String'
console.log(myArray.length) // got: 1
```

So basically the second element is not added to the array as the length have not changed. But when i log the array :

```
console.log(myArray) // got: ["A String", aRandomKey: "An Other String"]
```

i see that myArray has 2 elements ... So what's going on ?

Comment: When I log `myArray` in the Chrome console, I only see `["A String"]`

Comment: @MattLishman The behaviour described by OP [is correct](http://i.stack.imgur.com/beTfC.png) (screenshot is from the Chrome console).

Comment: @JamesThorpe I wasn't saying that it wasn't. What the OP says makes sense. I was just stating that I see something different in the console, indicating what they are attempting to do might be non standard.

Comment: Because second one is adding property to the array, not adding an index. Setting properties does not alter the length of the collection.

Comment: No, it has *one element* plus an arbitrary custom property. [Don't do this](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3mce3700/)

```
var myArray = []
myArray.push('A String')
console.log(myArray.length) // got: 1
myArray['aRandomKey']='An Other String'
console.log(myArray.length) // got: 1
```

Few more things

```
myArray[1] = "2nd string";
console.log(myArray.length);// you'll get 2

console.log(myArray.aRandomKey); // An Other String
console.log(myArray["aRandomKey"]); // An Other String
console.log(myArray) // ["A String", "2nd string", aRandomKey: "An Other String"]
```

By looking at the above statements, only if you use `push()` or assign using an integer key `myArray[1]`, the value gets pushed into the array. If you add a non-number key instead of an integer, it still gets added to the array object as a property but doesn't get pushed as an item and can be accessed by the object notation like above.

***Note***: Beware while adding an item to the array in this fashion `myArray[1] = "2nd string";` For example, if you write like this `myArray[1000] = "2nd string";console.log(myArray)`, the result looks like `["A String", 1000: "2nd string", aRandomKey: "An Other String"]` and length will be `1001`

Comment: No, if you assign `myArray[1000]` then `myArray.length` will be `1001`. The `.length` is pretty magic, it does not count consecutive elements only but the maximum index.

Comment: You should drop the whole "Note", there is no such thing as a "valid index". There are *sparse arrays* though if you're looking for a technical term.

Comment: @Bergi - my intention behind the note was if someone writes a `for` loop or something similar and accidently increments by a large number and one shouldn't expect that the array will add elements in a sequence.

Comment: A `for` loop would iterate 1001 indices, even if most of them yield `undefined` on access when no property exists? There
'

Comment: I edited the note so that it has nothing to do with the property.